# Authentication with middleware on Laravel Http Client Response API

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, middleware

I want to authenticate my middleware on laravel when the http client response is true and returns bearer token

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the authentication in laravel and want to return that generated token i would suggest you to do some basic research as there are so many  options available

I would suggest you to use  JWT token
https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/

may  be this can help you

Comment: no the issue is i am doing a laravel project with api,  the login api response provides a bearer token so in this front end how could a set a middleware auth

Comment: according to me that bearer token must be set in  Auhtorization header